# Wagtail image search works intermittently

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm working on a website built using Wagtail CMS. Sometimes, a search for images doesn't return anything even when an image that should match the search term is present. An example is in the screenshots below. There's an image titled "wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper3", but searching for part or all of this title doesn't find the image.

[The wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper3 image in the CMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkqFs.png)
[The result of searching for the wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper3 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvuZa.png)

Other times, the search returns the images it's expected to.

[The result of searching for an image titled "White House"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkNPK.png)

As far as I know, the site uses Wagtail's default images page and search functionality without any modifications. After looking at Wagtail's [source code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/a63689869e330044d8ea6435b219ceb42c706dbc/wagtail/images/models.py#L327) it seems that images should be searchable by their title by default.

Also, if it makes any difference, the images are stored in S3.

Does anyone know why the image search isn't working properly, and anything I could try to fix it?

I've tried checking the settings.py file to see if the search settings aren't set correctly. But, they are set correctly with the code snippet below:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "wagtail.search.backends.database",
        "AUTO_UPDATE": True,
    }
}
```

Comment: What database are you using? and does the behavior change if you reindex (manage.py update_index)

Comment: Running python manage.py update_index solved the problem. Thanks!